# Representing functions as power series and finding $c_0,c_1,c_2$...

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have a problem with representing functions as power series:
[question http://puu.sh/hvUGb/b48c3a9217.png](http://puu.sh/hvUGb/b48c3a9217.png)

I was trying to find $c_0$, $c_1$, $c_2$, ... and the Radius of Convergence but I'm not sure how to do this, I'm a bit lost here could someone give me some advice or help on this?

Comment: Do you know the power series expansion of $1/(1-y)$? Can you modify this somehow to cover the function you're given?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** One may recall that $$\frac{1}{1-q}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} q^n,\quad |q|<1.$$ Here you may put $q=8x$ and the **radius of convergence** is obtained from $x$ such that $|8x|<1$.